# Can't launder(void), therefore free() is UB?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to determine what the strictly conforming pattern for using memory allocators with C++17 is. Specifically, moving away from the working in practice UB pattern:

`example * foo = (example*)malloc(sizeof(example));` // no object here, don't use foo!

Therefore placement new into the allocated memory. Something like:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

struct example { // alignment <= max_align_t
  example(int x) : x(x) {}
  ~example() {}
  int x;

  static void *operator new(size_t, example *p) { return p; }
};

int main() {

  example *ex = nullptr;

  {
    void *m = malloc(sizeof(example));
    if (!m) {
      return 1;
    }

    ex = new (reinterpret_cast<example *>(m)) example(42);

    // if one failed to store the result of the new expression, can retrieve it
    // from m via launder
    ex = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<example *>(m));

    // now abandon all further instances of 'void *m'
  }

// ... do some well defined things with the example object at *ex
```

All good, we have a properly constructed object. How do we free it?

```
// ...
  {
    ex->~example(); // lifetime has ended

    // UB? We don't have a void* to pass to free
    // free(ex);

    // equivalent to above, it's still not a void*
    // free(reinterpret_cast<void*>(ex));

    // error, new defines: void launder(void*) = delete
    // free(std::launder(reinterpret_cast<void*>(ex)));

    // error: void pointer argument to __builtin_launder is not allowed
    // free( __builtin_launder(reinterpret_cast<void*>(ex)));

    // Quoting the rule book, 21.6.4 [ptr.launder]
    // The program is ill-formed if T is a function type or cv void

    // Out of options, guess it has to be free
    free(ex);
  }
}
```

`void *` doesn't have the aliasing properties of a `char*`. Can't even do arithmetic on void*.

'Free' is a difficult thing to search for. I can't see special case magic for free, but even if there is such, it won't help with platform_allocate/platform_deallocate pairs.

On the basis that launder definitely doesn't permit one to get the void* back, free(ex) in the above is presumably the right thing to do.

What makes free(ex) well defined?

Why is launder(void) forbidden? A pointer optimisation barrier applied at the end of the malloc() implementation seems a great idea.

Comment: Given this is a C++ question why `malloc` instead of `new`? What is the goal here? This all looks like a bunch of pointless sorcery to me. If you need a custom allocator why not just write one instead of hacking around like this?

Comment: That "free" code could get skipped if your destructor blows a gasket and pops an exception.

Comment: I've got a custom allocator. It wraps various trickery to share state between a cpu and gpus across pcie. I'm trying to work out how to use it without violating the C++ object model.

Broadly true about exceptions skipping over free, but that's easily solvable. Raii etc. Orthogonal to how to spell free.

Comment: If you have a custom allocator then you can just use regular `new` and `delete` and avoid all of this mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What makes free(ex) well defined?

`free` requires a pointer whose address is one directly returned by a call to `malloc`. You have provided that. Why wouldn't it work?

> Why is launder(void) forbidden?

Because it makes no sense. `std::launder<T>` returns a pointer to an object of type `T` within its lifetime whose address is the address of the given pointer. `void` is an incomplete type; there cannot be objects of type `void`. Therefore, `std::launder<void>` cannot possibly function.

Memory allocation functions typically do not deal with pointers to objects. They deal in pointers to *memory*. The only thing they care about is whether the address of that pointer is one they can deal with.

Comment: I don't believe reasoning in terms of addresses is permitted in C++ Otherwise the operator new that does nothing is difficult to explain, likewise the aliasing constraints. I'm not sure that (long)m==(long)ex is guaranteed either.

Comment: Void being incomplete explains unsupported launder(void*), that seems consistent.

Comment: @JonChesterfield: "*I don't believe reasoning in terms of addresses is permitted in C++*" Um... why not? Can you cite something in the standard that says that pointers aren't addresses? Indeed, the entire point of `launder` is to transform a pointer's address into a pointer to a live object at that address. If you can't "reason in terms of addresses," `launder` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I can't, but I also can't find anything that states pointers are not objects. I suppose we are creating a void* by casting, we're initializing one that just just been created.

Comment: @JonChesterfield: "*I also can't find anything that states pointers are not objects.*" What do you mean by that? Pointers themselves are objects; they take up storage and they have a value representation. Casting one pointer type to another creates a new pointer object whose value is what the standard says it is, relative to the original value, just like casting an `int` into a `short` returns a new object whose value is whatever the `int` to `short` conversion rules say it is.

Comment: @JonChesterfield: What's being discussed is the meaning of the *value of the pointer*, not of the pointer itself. `launder` returns a new pointer object which points to a particular object at the address pointed to by the pointer object it was given. `free` releases memory at the address pointed to by the pointer object it was given.

Comment: My comment is missing a 'not', should have been 'we are not creating a void* by casting'. It seems fairly clear that c++17 casting can't begin an object lifetime. I've finally caught the thread - creating a void* pointing to somewhere is much like creating an int, as it should be.